# Generation of all numbers of arbitrary length and base

Tags: haskell

`quux (['0'..9'] ++ ['A'..F']) 2` generates hexademical numbers of length 2 (with leading zeros), but it's obviously possible to generate any base and any length.

```
quux digits length = iterate foo return !! length $ [] where  
    foo bb aa = map (: aa) digits >>= bb
```

Can this code be simplified, while retaining the idea of iterating in list monad?

Comment: Is this just `replicateM`, except specialized to lists?

Comment: flip replicateM :) you can put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is exactly what `replicateM` does in the `[]` monad. For the sake of completeness, let's look at exactly how `replicateM` works.

```
replicateM :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a]
replicateM n x = sequence (replicate n x)

replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
replicate n x = [ x | _ <- [1..n] ]
```

`replicateM` turns out to just pass off the heavy lifting to `replicate` and `sequence`. `replicate` is pretty simple, so the interesting part happens in sequence:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
sequence [] = return []
sequence (x:xs) = do
    x'  <- x
    xs' <- sequence xs
    return (x' : xs')
```

And in fact, that's exactly what leaning on the `[]` monad instance for iteration looks like. A couple of binds and a return.